# without vendors but with vendor-dependant code ...?

Tags: symfony

Why is the vendorless version shipped (of course) without vendors, but in autoload.php and AppKernel.php vendor-bundles are loaded?

Even more confusing ... why shipping an example controller 
- with a Twig-template when there is no Twig-bundle
- with a YAML-routing without the YAML-component
- ...

wouldn't it make more sense to have the vendor-less version being shipped really without any vendor-specific code?

Then you could start adding instead of starting with removing!

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Symfony Standard 2.0.0` distribution available for download from the [Symfony download page](http://symfony.com/download) is not meant to be a non-vendor-dependent version of Symfony. It's simply shipped without vendors so that they can be installed (and kept up to date) with the `bin/vendors` script (which requires Git to function). The "with vendors" download is provided if you don't not have Git, or if you want to get started immediately with very litle setup whatsoever.

If you truly want Symfony with no 3rd-party dependent code, try the core framework repository, available at https://github.com/symfony/symfony.

Comment: interesting! so that means that Symfony without vendors is not just what I thought it is: "Symfony with vendors" and the vendors folder removed.